# JDBC result set for code connecting Java and MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database using Java. I want to grab all the entries for two row from two rows in a database and put them into the class ExpertScore. I then want to put the newly created ExpertScore objects into an array of ExpertScore objects. After this I want to run them through a method that takes an array of ExpertScore objects as input.  However, I run the code and get this error. Some debugging indicates that I think the problem results from the count of the result object.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:841)
 at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2672)
 at ZScoreCalc.main(ZScoreCalc.java:106)
```

This is my code that leads to the error:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException{
     System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
     Connection conn = null;
     String url = "jdbc:mysql:*";    // server address
     String dbName = "QA";   //table name
     String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"; // jdbc driver
     String userName = "*";   //username
     String password = "*";    //password
     Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
     try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
      System.out.println("Connected to the database");

      for(int j=1; j<11; j++){
      String query = "select * from CONSUMER_EXPERT_SCORE where CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID="+j;
      String queryforcount = "select count(*) from CONSUMER_EXPERT_SCORE where CONSUMER_EXPERT_ID="+j;
      PreparedStatement pscount = conn.prepareStatement(queryforcount);
      ResultSet resultcount = pscount.executeQuery();
      int count = resultcount.getInt(0);
      PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
      ResultSet result = ps.executeQuery();
      int i=0;
      ExpertScore[] allUsers=new ExpertScore[count];
      while(result.next()){
       double expert=result.getDouble(3);
       int id=result.getInt(2);
       ExpertScore current=new ExpertScore(id, j, expert);
       allUsers[i]=current;
       i++;
      }
      ZScoreCalc scrCalc = new ZScoreCalc();
         scrCalc.Z_Calc(allUsers);
         scrCalc.print();
      }

     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     } 

}
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? Sorry I am new to programming and particularly new to JDBC.

Comment: I strongly recommend you edit out your IP/username/password info from your question.  Oh and change your mysql password.

Comment: @Bill: Good idea, but too late, really

Comment: Your stacktrace says the error occurred on the call to getInt() on line 106.  There's more than one call to getInt() in your code.  Did you consider that we can't tell where line 106 is?.  Try calling pscount.close() before executing the next query.  The driver should do that automatically for you but with MySql, anything can happen.  Also, it's best practice to use the "?" place-holder in your SQL instead of "+j" and then call pscount.setInt(1, j) to establish the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `resultcount.next()` before calling `resultcount.getInt(0);`

And it's good practice to close your result sets in a finally clause.  Here is generally the structure you would want to use.

```
//in general use a structure like this:
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatemetn pStmt = null;
try {

 pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("Select * from foo");
 rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
 while (rs.next()) {
    String data = rs.getString(1);
 }
}
catch(Exception e){
 //handle exception
}
finally {
  try {
     if (rs != null) rs.close();
     if (pStmt != null) pStmt.close();
  }
  catch (Exception ignored) {
  }
}
```

}

Pro Tip:  For the common "close this resource an ignore exceptions" pattern, create utility methods:

```
class DbUtil {
    public void closeQuietly(ResultSet rs) {
      try {
         if (rs != null) rs.close();
      }
      catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }

    public void closeQuietly(Statement stmt) {
      try {
         if (stmt != null) stmt.close();
      }
      catch (Exception ignored) {}
    }
}
```